# javascript popups are not working in ie 11. when i open pop up it displays false on a blank screen

Tags: javascript

This is my code pop up opens on image click.when clicking on the image it shows false on the screen.

```
  <a href="javascript:openPopup()">
      <img src="images/register_button1.png" />
  </a>

    <script type="text/javascript">

            function openPopup() {
                var loginBox = $('#Popup');
                $(loginBox).fadeIn(300);
                var popMargTop = ($(loginBox).height() + 24) / 2;
                var popMargLeft = ($(loginBox).width() + 24) / 2;

                $(loginBox).css({
                    'margin-top': -popMargTop,
                    'margin-left': -popMargLeft
                });
                // Add the mask to body
                $('body').append('<div id="mask"></div>');
                $('#mask').fadeIn(300);
                return false;
            }
            $('a.close2').live('click', function() {
                $('#mask ,.login-popup').fadeOut(300, function() {
                    $('#mask').remove();
                    $('#Popup').hide();
                });
                return false;
            });
</script>
```

Comment: *"not working in ie 11"* - So it works in other versions of IE and other browsers like Chrome or FF?

Answer (score 0):

As [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) event has been depricated from latest version of JQuery. Try by using [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) Event:

```
 $('a.close2').on('click', function() {
                $('#mask ,.login-popup').fadeOut(300, function() {
                    $('#mask').remove();
                    $('#Popup').hide();
                });
                return false;
            });
```